# Write to a Python subprocess's stdin without communicate()'s blocking behavior

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, blocking

How do I make this a non-blocking call? `osd_cat` accepts input only as a `PIPE` which need `p.communicate()` call making the process to block. Is there any other way to set `stdin` in `Popen`?

```
p = subprocess.Popen(('osd_cat',
                      '-d',
                      '{}'.format(interval)),
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(message)
```

Comment: Use Python Multiprocessing and put your sub task in an other process.  Talk to it using a message queue.

Comment: Waitaminute, what you're stuck on is how else to feed to `stdin`? Have you tried `p.stdin.write()` before asking the question? (Yes, you'll want to do that in a separate thread to prevent blocking in the main process, but this is part of what threads are good for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`p.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) method is a one-shot deal in terms of sending data to the process.

Instead, write directly to [`p.stdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin). If you want to get output, you can read lines from [`p.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout). Make sure you pass `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to the constructor before attempting to read.

Comment: Why does `p.communicate` block though, when you pass a string? It could close pipe internally since we are passing a string..right?

Comment: @Jean. That's just what it's designed and documented to do. It optionally sends a single string, then waits for the process so close its stdout (usually by terminating). There's no particular overarching reason, except that that's a very common way to use processes. Perhaps it's the choice of name that's confusing?